# Formatos de saída do xml de webservice WCF

Tags: asp.net, web-service, xml

Tenho um webservice criado por WCF que gera o seguinte resultado em XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <feed xml:base="http://meudominio.com.br/WebServices/ABC.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"    
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<id>http://meudominio.com.br/webservices/ABC.svc/Clientes</id> 
<title type="text">Clientes</title> 
<updated>2015-11-25T16:06:46Z</updated> 
<link rel="self" title="Clientes" href="Clientes" /> 
- <entry>
  <id>http://meudominio.com.br/WebServices/ABC.svc/Clientes(cnae='',doc='40277279000170',email='',inscricao='',isAtivo='True',numeroDeFunc='',regional='28',telefone='%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20',tipoPessoa='1')</id> 
<category term="Model.Clientes" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
<link rel="edit" title="Clientes" href="Clientes(cnae='',doc='40277279000170',email='',inscricao='',isAtivo='True',numeroDeFunc='',regional='28',telefone='%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20',tipoPessoa='1')" /> 
<title /> 
<updated>2015-11-25T16:06:46Z</updated> 
- <author>
<name /> 
</author>
- <content type="application/xml">
- <m:properties>
<d:isAtivo>True</d:isAtivo> 
<d:tipoPessoa>1</d:tipoPessoa> 
<d:doc>40277279000170</d:cpfcnpj> 
<d:inscricaoEstadual /> 
<d:cnae /> 
<d:nome>EMPRESA</d:nome> 
<d:razaoSocial>EMPRESA LTDA. </d:razaoSocial> 
<d:telefone xml:space="preserve"></d:telefone> 
<d:email /> 
<d:numeroDeFunc /> 
<d:regional>28</d:regional> 
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível customizar essa saída. Gostaria que fosse publicado no webservice só a partir das tags que contem os dados que quero consumir e não todo esse cabeçalho inicial que saí default. Isso é possível?